# How to build iOS app for simulator using fastlane?

Tags: ios, jenkins, simulator, fastlane

For automation testing purposes I'm trying to build iOS app via **jenkins `job`** for *simulator* using **fastlane `build_app` script**.

Two things I'm currently having problems with are:

1. I don't know how to get `.app file` straight from build command
2. When I create `.ipa` file I get `.app file` simply by extracting the `.ipa`, but somehow that `.app` won't open on my simulator (simulator is
   the corresponding one)

The lane I'm using looks as following ->

```
lane :app_for_simulator do
    match(type: "development")
    build_app(
      scheme: "MyApp",
      export_method: "development",
      configuration: "Debug",
      destination: "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=13.1",
      output_name: "MyApp.ipa"
    )
  end
```

Has anyone had similar problems and managed to resolve them?

Looked across other topics but didn't manage to find the answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is what we use:

```
xcodebuild(
  {
    clean: true,
    build: true,
    workspace: "./MyApp.xcworkspace",
    output_name: "MyApp.ipa",
    scheme: "MyApp",
    sdk: "iphonesimulator",
    destination: "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s",
    xcargs: "ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO"
  }
)

# after the build we copy the MyApp.app from the build products
xcodebuild_dir = File.absolute_path("../MyApp/build/Build/Products/SimulatorBuild-iphonesimulator")
Actions.sh("ditto \"#{xcodebuild_dir}/MyApp.app\" \"MyApp.app\"")
```

Comment: Hi Lyndsey, thanks for your answer. However, this way I cannot choose tha path where my .ipa is going to be built. It goes in the default directory and that doesn't work for me since I have to have it inside my workspace. Is there a way to choose the output directory for my .ipa/.app?

Comment: The `.app` file will be created in a subdirectory of the derived data directory (which you can specify with `derivedDataPath`). It will be in `<derived data>/<project name>/build/Build/Products/<configuration name>/<app name>.app`.

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson May I know how to build `.app` instead of `.ipa`, that could be used for Simulator. BTW, thanks for your fastlane plugins.

Comment: @ZhouHaibo the command in this answer is how you can build an `.app` file for the Simulator. Does it not work for you?

Comment: @LyndseyFerguson because I saw you name it `MyApp.ipa`, thus I think it could be for real iPhone.

Comment: Eventually, I use this ```build_app(
      project: "MyApp.xcodeproj",
      scheme: "myScheme",
      configuration: "Development",
      skip_package_ipa: true,
      skip_archive: true,
      derived_data_path: "Derived_Data_Development/",
      destination: "generic/platform=iOS Simulator"
    )``` to output `MyApp.app`, which is from gym doc.

Comment: @ZhouHaibo I don't actually recall why we named it with the "ipa" extension; I don't work in that code anymore. I do see that after we run that command, we navigate to the "build" directory to copy the "MyApp.app" to the desired directory. I'll update my answer with that info.

Comment: Yeah, it is weird that iOS Simulator with IPA, which is for real IPhone.